# Can you please explain what 'mov dword[ss:rbp-0x0+var_m4], 0x0' does?

Tags: assembly

Please explain this line of code:

```
mov dword[ss:rbp-0x0+var_m4], 0x0
```

As far as i understood:

- it is a pointer
- but where does it point to?
- what does ss::rbp-0x0+var_m4 mean?
- rbp is the base pointer, right?

Comment: Since 0x0 is zero and ss is implied when the address uses rbp as the base, this can be read simply as `mov dword ptr[rbp+var_m4], 0`. It sets the stack-based variable at offset var_m4, relative to the current frame pointer, to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- it is a pointer
```

Sorta. At the assembly level, the notion of a "pointer" is a little less well-defined than at the level of a higher-level language like C or C++. It is, however, doing address arithmetic to compute the address to store data to.

```
- but where does it point to?
```

No idea. You'd have to look at earlier instructions, and the value of the `var_m4` label, and the current contents of the `rbp` register to know for sure.

```
- what does ss::rbp-0x0+var_m4 mean?
```

It calculates the memory address by adding the current contents of the `rbp` register, the label or constant value `var_m4`, and the immediate value `0`. The `ss:` segment prefix indicates whatever it is doing is on the stack, though. So, it's probably either a reference to an an element of an array allocated on your stack, or possibly a structure member or something.

```
- rbp is the base pointer, right?
```

Usually, although that register can be spilled and re-used for other things within the body of your function, depending on the optimization level and flags given to your compiler.